# Visual Studio 2013 Remote Debugging no local Variables

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, remote-debugging

I am trying to debug remote with my visual studio 2013.

The latest remote pckage is installed on the server.

I am able to connect to the process, break points are working and it works great so far.

Only problem is that i dnt have any local variables in studio so the remote debugging is kind of useless for me.

[image]

Any idea what i can do here?

Regards
Andre

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/6hyrghp9z/

As you can see
Breakpoint hits
The Locals window will stay like this

Comment: You'll have to deploy the Debug build if you need to inspect local variables.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Checked it but its already in debug :(